Logstash Scheduling: Getting FATAL ERRORjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jruby.RubyThread.beforeBlockingCall(org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext)
I have total 8 pipelines in logstash, i have scheduled all pipelines together but it runs alternate days . For example i have scheduled on 11th Oct, i runs on 13th and 15th and it skipped it on 12th, 14th,16th. But i need every it should run.
This is my pipelines.yml file.
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_1
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Flowstatus_prod.conf"

 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_2
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Flows_analytics_count.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_3
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/bw6_flows_analytics_count.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_4
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/bw6_legacyevp_loghdr.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_5
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Apigee_data.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_6
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Apigee_Prod.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_7
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/bw6_legacyevp_logdtl.conf"
              
 - pipeline.id: my-pipeline_8
   path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Logevent_prod.conf"`

and my configuration file example is :
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["https://host:port"]
        index => "index_name"
        query => '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"DATE": {"gte": "now-1d/d", "lt": "now/d", "format": "strict_date_optional_time"}}}, {"match": {"TRANSACTION_STATUS": "ERROR"}}]}}}'
        user => "User_name"
        password => "Password"
        ssl => true
        ca_file => "Path"
        schedule => "20 0 * * *"
    }
}

filter {
    # Add the current date and time to a new field
    ruby {
        code => "event.set('current_date', Time.now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))"
    }
              
    if [ERROR_MESSAGE] {
        ruby {
            code => "
            if event.get('ERROR_MESSAGE').is_a?(Array)
                # Join the array into a single string
                event.set('ERROR_MESSAGE', event.get('ERROR_MESSAGE').join(', '))
                end
            "
        }
     }
}

output {
    google_bigquery {
        project_id => "project_id"
        dataset => "dataset"
        table_prefix => "table_name"       
        table_separator => ""
        csv_schema => "FLOWID:STRING,FLOW_NAME:STRING,DATE:TIMESTAMP,TRACKING_ID:STRING,COMPONENT:STRING,TRANSACTION_STATUS:STRING,ERROR_MESSAGE:STRING,current_date:DATE"   
        json_key_file => "path/Prd_key_json_file_bigquery.json"
        error_directory => "/tmp/bigquery-errors"
        skip_invalid_rows => true
        ignore_unknown_values => true
        date_pattern => ""    `
    }
}


Increase heap size to 4GB in jvm.options file.
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g

Upgrade Elasticsearch input plugin

Give File permission to Logstash directory`


It is running alternated days, could you please help
